# Have logwatch send reports only once a week

Tags: linux, logs, email, logwatch

I would like to lessen the noise from `logwatch` reports sent to my email on three systems.

Is it possible by to configure logwatch to send only some days in the week, or once a week?

**More relevant data:**

[logwatch8-is-too-noisy-how-can-i-control-the-noise-level on SERVERFAULT](https://serverfault.com/questions/293226/linux-logwatch8-is-too-noisy-how-can-i-control-the-noise-level)

`/usr/share/logwatch/default.conf/logwatch.conf`:

```
########################################################
# This was written and is maintained by:
#    Kirk Bauer <kirk@kaybee.org>
#
# Please send all comments, suggestions, bug reports,
#    etc, to kirk@kaybee.org.
#
########################################################

# NOTE:
#   All these options are the defaults if you run logwatch with no
#   command-line arguments.  You can override all of these on the
#   command-line.

# You can put comments anywhere you want to.  They are effective for the
# rest of the line.

# this is in the format of <name> = <value>.  Whitespace at the beginning
# and end of the lines is removed.  Whitespace before and after the = sign
# is removed.  Everything is case *insensitive*.

# Yes = True  = On  = 1
# No  = False = Off = 0

# Default Log Directory
# All log-files are assumed to be given relative to this directory.
LogDir = /var/log

# You can override the default temp directory (/tmp) here
TmpDir = /var/cache/logwatch

#Output/Format Options
#By default Logwatch will print to stdout in text with no encoding.
#To make email Default set Output = mail to save to file set Output = file
Output = stdout
#To make Html the default formatting Format = html
Format = text
#To make Base64 [aka uuencode] Encode = base64
Encode = none

# Default person to mail reports to.  Can be a local account or a
# complete email address.  Variable Output should be set to mail, or
# --output mail should be passed on command line to enable mail feature.
MailTo = root
# WHen using option --multiemail, it is possible to specify a different
# email recipient per host processed.  For example, to send the report
# for hostname host1 to user@example.com, use:
#Mailto_host1 = user@example.com
# Multiple recipients can be specified by separating them with a space.

# Default person to mail reports from.  Can be a local account or a
# complete email address.
MailFrom = Logwatch

# if set, the results will be saved in <filename> instead of mailed
# or displayed. Be sure to set Output = file also.
#Filename = /tmp/logwatch

# Use archives?  If set to 'Yes', the archives of logfiles
# (i.e. /var/log/messages.1 or /var/log/messages.1.gz) will
# be searched in addition to the /var/log/messages file.
# This usually will not do much if your range is set to just
# 'Yesterday' or 'Today'... it is probably best used with Range = All
# By default this is now set to Yes. To turn off Archives uncomment this.
#Archives = No

# The default time range for the report...
# The current choices are All, Today, Yesterday
Range = Today

# The default detail level for the report.
# This can either be Low, Med, High or a number.
# Low = 0
# Med = 5
# High = 10
Detail = 10


# The 'Service' option expects either the name of a filter
# (in /usr/share/logwatch/scripts/services/*) or 'All'.
# The default service(s) to report on.  This should be left as All for
# most people.
Service = All
# You can also disable certain services (when specifying all)
Service = "-zz-network"     # Prevents execution of zz-network service, which
                            # prints useful network configuration info.
Service = "-zz-sys"         # Prevents execution of zz-sys service, which
                            # prints useful system configuration info.
Service = "-eximstats"      # Prevents execution of eximstats service, which
                            # is a wrapper for the eximstats program.
# If you only cared about FTP messages, you could use these 2 lines
# instead of the above:
#Service = ftpd-messages   # Processes ftpd messages in /var/log/messages
#Service = ftpd-xferlog    # Processes ftpd messages in /var/log/xferlog
# Maybe you only wanted reports on PAM messages, then you would use:
#Service = pam_pwdb        # PAM_pwdb messages - usually quite a bit
#Service = pam             # General PAM messages... usually not many

# You can also choose to use the 'LogFile' option.  This will cause
# logwatch to only analyze that one logfile.. for example:
#LogFile = messages
# will process /var/log/messages.  This will run all the filters that
# process that logfile.  This option is probably not too useful to
# most people.  Setting 'Service' to 'All' above analyzes all LogFiles
# anyways...

#
# By default we assume that all Unix systems have sendmail or a sendmail-like MTA.
# The mailer code prints a header with To: From: and Subject:.
# At this point you can change the mailer to anything that can handle this output
# stream.
# TODO test variables in the mailer string to see if the To/From/Subject can be set
# From here with out breaking anything. This would allow mail/mailx/nail etc..... -mgt
mailer = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t"

#
# With this option set to a comma separted list of hostnames, only log entries
# for these particular hosts will be processed.  This can allow a log host to
# process only its own logs, or Logwatch can be run once per a set of hosts
# included in the logfiles.
# Example: HostLimit = hosta,hostb,myhost
#
# The default is to report on all log entries, regardless of its source host.
# Note that some logfiles do not include host information and will not be
# influenced by this setting.
#
#HostLimit = myhost

# vi: shiftwidth=3 tabstop=3 et
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tell logwatch to look at 7 days instead of 1 day by changing the `Range` parameter in your logwatch.conf:

```
Range = between -7 days and -1 days
```

You can tell logwatch to run weekly instead of daily by moving it from the daily cron directory to the weekly cron directory:

```
mv /etc/cron.daily/00logwatch /etc/cron.weekly/
```

Comment: For me the file had a single leading `0`, not 2 as shown above

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand, you need to put exactly this for the **command line** version:

```
logwatch <options>  --range '-7 days'
```

Check the mail you get for confirmation, it should show the current date and the oldest checked log.

Comment: In output, period is still a set to a day.